# "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute" - Can someone explain the meaning of this error message?

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to get the ODB library working. In the documentation at https://python-obd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ it lists the following code:

```
import obd

connection = obd.OBD("/dev/ttyUSB0") # connects to USB or RF port

cmd = obd.commands.SPEED # select an OBD command (sensor)

response = connection.query(cmd) # send the command, and parse the response

print(response.value) # returns unit-bearing values thanks to Pint
print(response.value.to("mph")) # user-friendly unit conversions
```

When I put this in a file called test.py and I run it:

```
python2 test.py
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import obd
  File "/home/ubuntu/obd.py", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OBD'
```

Stackoverflow comes up with several iterations of this error message, but none clearly explain the problem, only giving specific solutions to those libraries.

I guess it's obvious that I'm new to Python, and I'm having trouble interpreting this error message, even after several hours of writing several small Python programs. I am of course also interested in why the error message is so un-intuitive to a newcomer and where I can gain the common knowledge I might be missing, and I guess this is as good a case to discover that through as any.

Comment: Don't name your file `obd.py`.

Comment: `obd` is a module object. It doesn't have an `OBD` attribute. So `obd.OBD` is an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Your `odb.py` shadows the `obd` package you want to import. As @user2357112supportsMonica said - rename your file.

Comment: My file is named test.py - and I did pip install obd, and the code is copy and paste from the obd module docs... please be patient with me, I am really lost.

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong error message, but it's still the same error message @buran

Comment: Looks like you've still got a `bar.pyc` file lingering from when your file was called `bar.py`. Delete that.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. I guess this is a fairly common Python newbie issue. Any good Python courses you can recommend? (That starts with how the linking/compiling works?)

Answer (score 0):

So far I have figured out the following:

`<module>` refers to the name of my python script that I am trying to run.

The mistake I made at first, was to name my `test.py` file, initially `obd.py`. This conflicted with the `import obd` as it was trying to import the file itself - even after I deleted it! The reason was that when I tried to run it the first time, it created a file called `obd.pyc` - and even though `obd.py` was no longer there, `import OBD` found the initially created `obd.pyc` and tried to import that - which of course does not contain the OBD object from the library I was trying to use.

This is not the detailed answer I'm looking for, so please add a more detailed explanation - or a link to how Python compiling works, if you can.